# Trying to handle segmented control switch inside of navigation bar title view

Tags: swift, uinavigationcontroller, uisegmentedcontrol

I created a segmented control using

```
private let updateSwitch: UISegmentedControl = {
    let sc = UISegmentedControl(items: ["Sign In", "Sign Out"])
    sc.anchor(width: 128, height: 32)
    sc.selectedSegmentIndex = 0
    sc.tintColor = .mainBlue
    sc.backgroundColor = .mainGray
    sc.addTarget(self, action: #selector(handleSegmentedControlSwitch(_:)), for: .valueChanged)
    return sc
}()
```

I then added updateSwitch to my navigation bar using

```
navigationItem.titleView = updateSwitch
```

The segmented control shows up completely fine but whenever I select either sign in or sign out, the selector code does not get executed

```
@objc func handleSegmentedControlSwitch(_ segmentedControl: UISegmentedControl) {
    switch(segmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex) {
        case 0:
            print("Sign In")
        break
        case 1:
            print("Sign Out")
        break
        default:
        break
    }
}
```

Any idea on how I can fix this?

Attached is an image of the working segmented control

[image: image of working segmented control]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because of your UISegmentControl declaration.

You have 2 ways:

### 1. declare it as a **lazy var**:

because **Self** in lazy var is valid.

```
    private lazy var updateSwitch: UISegmentedControl = {
     let sc = UISegmentedControl(items: ["Sign In", "Sign Out"])
     sc.anchor(width: 128, height: 32)
     sc.selectedSegmentIndex = 0
     sc.tintColor = .mainBlue
     sc.backgroundColor = .mainGray
     sc.addTarget(self, action: #selector(handleSegmentedControlSwitch(_:)), for: .valueChanged)
    return sc }()
```

### 2. assign action in viewDidLoad

```
    override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    let segmented = self.updateSwitch
    segmented.addTarget(self, action: #selector(handleSegmentedControlSwitch(_:)), for: .valueChanged)
    navigationItem.titleView = segmented
}
```